# C++ 20 in clang compiler

Tags: clang, cygwin, c++20

I want to use clang compiler in my Windows 10 OS so i downloaded the Cygwin and installed it. Generally compilation works but when i set flag `-std=c++20` (or -std=c++2a) clang generates some errors:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "Hello world!!!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/iostream:39:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ostream:38:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ios:42:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/string:55:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/ext/alloc_traits.h:34:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:263:4: error:
      no member named 'construct_at' in namespace 'std'; did you mean
      'construct'?
          std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:360:2: note:
      'construct' declared here
        construct(_Alloc& __a, _Tp* __p, _Args&&... __args)
        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:518:4: error:
      no member named 'construct_at' in namespace 'std'; did you mean
      'construct'?
          std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:511:2: note:
      'construct' declared here
        construct(allocator_type& __a __attribute__((__unused__)), _Up* __p,
        ^
2 errors generated.
```

Clang installed on Ubuntu in VM works properly so where here may be problem? I suppose environment variable but if this could be problem how to set them properly?

I tried to reinstall clang with Cygwin tool for checking how works other versions or sources libs/compilers. I checked if this problem appeared before other ones. I expected the instructions how to exactly and properly install clang on Windows 10 to everything would like to work but i didn't find it.

Comment: Please show a [mre] of code that can be used to generate the error.

Comment: OK.

```cpp

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    
 cout<<"Hello world!!!"<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: I do not believe that that program will result in the error you show in the question. If It actually does, I'd stop using that implementation.

Comment: But it is true, only with flag -std=c++20 (with others, like -std=c++17 it works). And what's interesting: errors are in Clang installed in Windows 10 by Cygwin (which emulates Linux OS on Windows). Clang installed in Linux works very well.

Comment: In that case, I'd stop using that implementation. Have you tried using WSL2 instead of Gygwin? Your program compiles clean with `clang++ -std=c++20` in WSL2.

Comment: Don´t use Cygwin, it has a very specific and limited use case. Install Msys2 instead, and from within Msys2 install clang and everything else you need. It works.

Comment: Msys2, do You mean g++ compiler?

Comment: No I mean https://www.msys2.org/ There is a fairly large package list in there, including clang.